# How do I get StoneSense to work?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What do I have to change to get [StoneSense 2.0 Slate RC2](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=43260.0) to work with Dwarf Fortress 0.31.12?
Right now it's hanging at "Connecting to DF..." for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to backup Memory.xml in Stonesence folder and replace its content with http://pastebin.com/8Kg1AnKb